# how to disable Jquery simplyScroll mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, simplyscroll

I need disable only mouse hover for jquery simplyScroll plugin?
Client ask only click function ...
please any one help me?
thanks in advance... :)

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
            auto: false,
            speed: 50
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what u need is to disable the scrolling when mouse over is it?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if i got your question right, but if you want to disable the "pause on mouseover" function

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
            auto: false,
            speed: 50,
            pauseOnHover : false    // <--- just use the option
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

..should do the trick.
as seen in the manual http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/